# Error Importing Design Package in Design Manager

Tags: 2013, design-manager

Ran into a strange problem today trying to import a custom design package using design manager.  The solution uploads just fine but then i get an error:

> Sorry, something went wrong
>
> Value cannot be null.
>
> Parameter name: g
>
> TECHNICAL DETAILS

Here is the log file entry:

> Error installing design package:
>
> Design Package Install: an error occurred while installing package
>   'Spillman_Brand-1.4.wsp'  at web /. Error: Value cannot be null. 
>   Parameter name: g Stacktrace:    at System.Guid..ctor(String g)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserSolutionCollection.Add(Int32
>   solutionGalleryItemId)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.DesignPackage.<>c_*DisplayClass1.b*_0()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.<>c_*DisplayClass5.b*_3()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated
>   secureCode)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(WaitCallback
>   secureCode, Object param)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(CodeToRunElevated
>   secureCode)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.DesignPackage.Install(SPSite site,
>   DesignPackageInfo info, Stream data)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.CodeBehind.DesignPackageInstall.<>c_*DisplayClass1.b*_0(SPLongOperation
>   longOperation)

I tried uploading it directly to the solution gallery but it will not activate.

I also tried a different site collection and it works just fine.

Tried turning the publishing feature off and then on again.

Any ideas?

Comment: what is your feature scope? Try changing the feature scope to Farm or Site.

Comment: Is it possible to change the feature scope this way?  I exported a design package and tried to import it to another site.  Never saw an option for the feature scope.  It also works on other site collections no problem.